# WPS Parameters Wifi NFC and Android

Tags: android, wifi, nfc, android-wifi

[Handover-NFC](http://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CEcQFjAC&url=http://www.maintag.fr/fichiers/pdf-fr/nfcforum-ts-connectionhandover-1-1.pdf&ei=919oT-XXD8yB4ASLn-CyCQ&usg=AFQjCNEuVffP4lLEjdGMcU_ulkgCnz-eRQ&sig2=mDtSI_EQdTMHCqwsdvMF4A)

On Page 23, a wps record is saved and in the content column are defined "constants".

For example
WPS Attribute: SSID is given by 0x1045 
WPS Attribute: Encryption Type is given by 0x100F 
Encryption Type: AES is given by 0x0008

I would need a specification or a website where these constants are listed. I don't want to buy the wifi spec (about 200$) and maybe somone knows a goog website?

Is there also a way to safe GroupCipher and Pairwisecipher? Because here is just Encryption Type given, but I want do distinct between this 2 Parameters for Wificonfiguration on Android.

Comment: Does my answer here help you at all? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36758225/creating-an-ndef-wifi-record-using-application-vnd-wfa-wsc-in-android