# Creating an NDEF WiFi record using application/vnd.wfa.wsc in Android

Tags: java, android, wifi, nfc, ndef

As of Android 5.0.0 you can long tap on a WiFi connection and write that connection to a tag ("Write to NFC tag"). You can find the source for that operation here: [WriteWifiConfigToNfcDialog.java](http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/wifi/WriteWifiConfigToNfcDialog.java). The relevant line that takes a WiFi connection and creates an NDEF payload appears to be here:

`String wpsNfcConfigurationToken = mWifiManager.getWpsNfcConfigurationToken(mAccessPoint.networkId);`

`mWifiManager` is an instance of `WifiManager`, however `getWpsNfcConfigurationToken` is not part of the API. By tracking down this method, we can find its commit here: [Add calls for NFC WSC token creation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/b2e6bfd%5E!/) which is unfortunately no help. *This is where my investigation has run out.* Edit: 
I've found out the following call stack:

`WifiServiceImpl.java` calls  `mWifiStateMachine.syncGetWpsNfcConfigurationToken(netId);`

`WifiStateMachine.java` calls `mWifiNative.getNfcWpsConfigurationToken(netId);`

`WifiNative.java` finally has the method

`public String getNfcWpsConfigurationToken(int netId) {
        return doStringCommand("WPS_NFC_CONFIG_TOKEN WPS " + netId);
    }`

which then calls

`String result = doStringCommandNative(mInterfacePrefix + command);`

where `doStringCommandNative` makes a system call (can't find the code for this anywhere).

Which is now where the investigation ends.

Hoping someone can step in and show me a method that creates an `NdefRecord` that is of the type `application/vnd.wfa.wsc` given  an SSID, Password, Encryption/Auth type.

I've of course inspected the bytes of an actual `application/vnd.wfa.wsc` record created by Android but manually recreating this process with the bytes seems potentially very unreliable and is incredibly tedious.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer lies in the Wi-Fi Alliance "Wi-Fi Simple Configuration Technical Specification v2.0.5" (available for download [here](https://www.wi-fi.org/downloads-registered-guest/Wi-Fi_Simple_Configuration_Technical_Specification_v2.0.5.pdf/29560)). Android makes use of this standard format for configuring WiFi networks, I wrongly assumed it was proprietary.

Firstly, I created an NFC helper class (aptly named [NFCHelper.java](https://gist.github.com/henrycjc/5e161e0c1327313b20b4773526f02a06)) which has all the byte constants needed to construct the record. Then, I created a hacky method for creating one of the two records required. The spec is actually fairly useless here, what I did was examined a number of payloads of tags that had been successfully configured via the Android OS. Finally, you need to have a mechanism to prepend a "Handover Select Record (NFC WKT Hs)" (see page 90 of WiFi spec). I believe this record "tells" Android to register the network in the following token.

How to create the handover record:

```
ndefRecords = new NdefRecord[2];
byte[] version = new byte[] { (0x1 << 4) | (0x2)};
ndefRecords[0] = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, NdefRecord.RTD_HANDOVER_REQUEST, new byte[0], version);
// and then obviously add the record you create with the method below.
```

Method for creating the configuration token:

```
private NdefRecord createWifiRecord(String[] data) {
    String ssid = data[0];
    String password = data[1];
    String auth = data[2];
    String crypt = data[3];
    byte[] authByte = getAuthBytes(auth);
    byte[] cryptByte = getCryptBytes(crypt);
    byte[] ssidByte = ssid.getBytes();
    byte[] passwordByte = password.getBytes();
    byte[] ssidLength = {(byte)((int)Math.floor(ssid.length()/256)), (byte)(ssid.length()%256)};
    byte[] passwordLength = {(byte)((int)Math.floor(password.length()/256)), (byte)(password.length()%256)};
    byte[] cred = {0x00, 0x36};
    byte[] idx = {0x00, 0x01, 0x01};
    byte[] mac = {0x00, 0x06};
    byte[] keypad = {0x00, 0x0B};

    byte[] payload = concat(NFCHelper.CREDENTIAL, cred,
            NFCHelper.NETWORK_IDX, idx,
            NFCHelper.NETWORK_NAME, ssidLength, ssidByte,
            NFCHelper.AUTH_TYPE, NFCHelper.AUTH_WPA_PERSONAL, authByte,
            NFCHelper.CRYPT_TYPE, NFCHelper.CRYPT_WEP, NFCHelper.CRYPT_AES_TKIP,
            NFCHelper.NETWORK_KEY, passwordLength, passwordByte);
           // NFCHelper.MAC_ADDRESS, mac);
    return NdefRecord.createMime(NFC_TOKEN_MIME_TYPE, payload);
}
```

License and gist [here](https://gist.github.com/henrycjc/17f3de5118c5c9d8a7a4e6840d601109). You can find an implementation of the `concat` method anywhere on the net, or just write your own.

**Note**: this is a fairly hacky implementation (as you may notice). I am including the AES and AES/TKIP bytes as I found in testing it worked for a variety of networks using different encryption/auth methods under Android 5.* 
Please feel free to change the function prototype, the String array just worked nicely with what I was doing.

Using the two records created in the first snippet above, you should then pass that into an `NdefMessage` and write it to your tag.

One day soon I'm going to do a write up and a far better/robust soln with graphics and stuff too, so I'll update this answer then.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and your code. It's not nearly as hacky as I'd have expected. :D

Answer (score 7):

The call of `doStringCommand("WPS_NFC_CONFIG_TOKEN WPS " + netId)` in the end is handled by the *wpa_supplicant* module. This feature is described [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/wpa_supplicant_8/+/master/wpa_supplicant/README-WPS#338). I think the actual implementation of this can be found in [wps_supplicant.c](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/wpa_supplicant_8/+/master/wpa_supplicant/wps_supplicant.c).

What you are actually trying to do isn't something Android specific actually. It's defined in the "WiFi Simple Configuration Technical Specification", which you can download by filling [this form](https://www.wi-fi.org/downloads-registered-guest/Wi-Fi_Simple_Configuration_Technical_Specification_v2.0.5.pdf/29560). The relevant part should be *10.1.2 Configuration Token*.

[NfcUtils.java](https://github.com/bparmentier/WiFiKeyShare/blob/master/app/src/main/java/be/brunoparmentier/wifikeyshare/utils/NfcUtils.java) has a working implementation for this! There are a few FIXMEs and TODOs, but in total it works and should give you a pretty good idea of what you need to do.

In case you want to parse such NdefRecords yourself and do something with the SSID and key, [NfcWifiProtectedSetup.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Nfc/+/android-5.0.2_r1/src/com/android/nfc/NfcWifiProtectedSetup.java) shows how to do that.

Comment: First of all, thank you for tracking down `wps_supplicant.c`. Second, while I haven't updated the original question in some time, I was able to create the Wifi record! I just wasn't very happy with the solution (and not overly proud as it is fairly hacky). I indeed acquired a copy of the "WiFi Simple Configuration Technical Specification" (version 2.0.0) and was able to follow the specification - the most important part was the Handover Record which I didn't even think of. I'll post my code as an answer.

Comment: @Henry I had quite some trouble reading and understanding the specification so far. Since I'm currently trying to do this as well, I'm looking forward to see how you did it!