# Decoding Raw NFC Payload

Tags: windows, nfc, ndef

I am trying to decode the payload from an NFC chip that I programmed on a Windows machine in NFC Tools so that I can understand the syntax of WiFi records for use in writing tags via another windows software, GoToTags.

NFC Tools lets me write a WiFi record and then I can read it with NFC Tools to see the Mime Type and Payload, but the Payload is raw and I need to get it to ASCII so that I can write tags the other software, GoToTags.

```
▪▪ DATA ▪▪
Network Name: SSID
Authentication Type: WPA/WP2 PERSONAL
Encryption Type: AES
Password: password

▪▪ FORMAT ▪▪
Media (0x02)
Defined by RFC 2046

▪▪ TYPE ▪▪
application/vnd.wfa.wsc

▪▪ PAYLOAD ▪▪
0x10 0x0E 0x00 0x2F 0x10 
0x26 0x00 0x01 0x01 0x10 
0x45 0x00 0x04 0x53 0x53 
0x49 0x44 0x10 0x03 0x00 
0x02 0x00 0x22 0x10 0x0F 
0x00 0x02 0x00 0x08 0x10 
0x27 0x00 0x08 0x70 0x61 
0x73 0x73 0x77 0x6F 0x72 
0x64 0x10 0x20 0x00 0x06 
0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 
0xFF

▪▪ PAYLOAD (UTF8) ▪▪
/&ESSID"'password ������

▪▪ PAYLOAD (ASCII) ▪▪
/&ESSID"'password ������
```

As you can see, the UTF8 and ASCII payloads have some unknown characters, so I was hoping to get the information I need from the raw payload instead.

Ultimately, I would like to be able to write records that exist in the NFC Tools software (Bluetooth records, for example) in the GoToTags software using the custom Mime Type record.

Comment: Answer probably in https://stackoverflow.com/a/38742879/2373819

Comment: Thanks, @Andrew, but I should have mentioned that my technical background is severely limited in programming. I will examine that post further and see if I can understand it. So far, I'm not able to!